# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd

Tags: java, xhtml, xslt, xalan

In the following code:

```
private Document transformDoc(Source source) throws TransformerException, IOException {
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

    Transformer transformer =
            factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltResource.getInputStream()));
    JDOMResult result = new JDOMResult();
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    return result.getDocument();
}
```

I get this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
```

The XHTML I'm translating over via xsl is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
  <title>Terms and Conditions</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>Test Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I stop the xalan transformer from phoning home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post from the Xalan-J mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox//xml-xalan-j-users/200405.mbox/%3COF11813749.87BF70C0-ON85256E8A.00551F74-85256E8A.0060DD22@ca.ibm.com%3E) suggests that "the right way" is for you to configure the underlying `Source`/`Reader` yourself to disable validation.

Comment: You need the following to get it 100% right, but that mailing list link was most helpful!

     SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        spf.setValidating(false);  // Turn off validation
        spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
        XMLReader rdr = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();

Answer (score 2):

Either disable DTD resolving in the parser (parser-specific) or set an empty entity resolver.

Copied from http://www.jdom.org/docs/faq.html#a0350:

```
public class NoOpEntityResolver implements EntityResolver {
  public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) {
    return new InputSource(new StringBufferInputStream(""));
  }
}

// Then in the builder...

builder.setEntityResolver(new NoOpEntityResolver());
```